# ConTeXt : specific item behavior

Tags: context, itemize

I'm trying to have a different behavior for itemize inside a given environment, but I can't make it work. I tried to use the before option, as in the following MWE

```
\defineframedtext[special]
             [before={\setupitemize[each][3,packed]},
               width=max]
%% document
\starttext
\startspecial
  Hello
  \startitemize  %% default behavior : not ok
    \item foo bar
    \item \input knuth
  \stopitemize
\stopspecial
\startspecial
  Hello
  \startitemize[3]  %% what I would like to be automatic
    \item foo bar
    \item \input knuth    
  \stopitemize
\stopspecial
\stoptext
```

Can you explain me what option may work please ?

## EDIT

I tried the answer given by Metafox, which worked on the MWE, but not on my real document. With more work, I found that my global setting was taken even in the new framed block.

```
\setupitemize[1][2,packed]  %% this line is the problem

\startsetups[framedtext:special]
    \setupitemize[each][3,packed]
\stopsetups
\defineframedtext[special]
             [inner={\directsetup{framedtext:special}},
               width=max]

%% document
\starttext
\startspecial
  Hello
  \startitemize  %% not ok
    \item foo bar
    \item \input knuth
  \stopitemize
\stopspecial
\stoptext
```

Is there a way to make this setting prevalent in the new framedtext environment ?

Comment: `\setupitemize[1]` takes precedence over `\setupitemize[each]`. You should also include `\setupitemize[1][2,packed]` in your setups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arguments of the `before` and `after` keys are applied after the content of the environment is typeset. To add setups which are local to the environment you can use the `inner` key.

```
\defineframedtext
  [special]
  [inner={\setupitemize[each][3,packed]},
   width=max]

\starttext

\startspecial
  Hello
  \startitemize
    \item foo bar
    \item \input knuth
  \stopitemize
\stopspecial

\stoptext
```

[image: Local settings for itemize in a framed text environment]

When your setups are longer you can put them into a `setups` environment and load it with the `inner` key.

```
\startsetups[framedtext:special]
    \setupitemize[each][3,packed]
\stopsetups

\defineframedtext
  [special]
  [inner=\directsetup{framedtext:special},
   width=max]
```

To ensure global settings are overwritten you should use `1,2,...` instead of the `each` keyword for the first argument of the `\setupitemize` command because unlike in MkII the `each` keyword in MkIV doesn’t overwrite level specific settings anymore.

```
\startsetups[framedtext:special]
    \setupitemize[1,2,3,4][3,packed]
\stopsetups
```